# Powershell with Shutdown command error handling

Tags: powershell, shutdown

My shutdown script using the `Shutdown -R` command to do a mass reboot of machines.  If the `Shutdown -R` throws a error like "RPC Service Unavailable, or access denied" I can't catch it or just don't know how to.  Can someone help?  I don't want to use Restart-Computer in powershell since you can't delay the reboot and can't add comments.

```
foreach($PC in $PClist){
ping -n 2 $PC >$null
if($lastexitcode -eq 0){
  write-host "Rebooting $PC..." -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor green
  shutdown /r /f /m \\$PC /d p:1:1 /t 300 /c "$reboot_reason"
  LogWrite "$env:username,$PC,Reboot Sent,$datetime"
} else {
  write-host "$PC is UNAVAILABLE" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor red
  LogWrite "$env:username,$PC,Unavailable/Offline,$datetime"
}
}
```

Comment: In PowerShell 3.0 there is actually a -Delay parameter, but not a reason parameter...

Comment: Are you unable to use $lastexitcode after your shutdown command to check for a non-zero return code? I would be surprised if it returns 0 when an RPC Service or other error occurs (though I haven't checked this)

Comment: The PowerShell -Delay parameter is not for delaying the reboot. Instead it "Determines how often Windows PowerShell queries the service that is specified by the For parameter to determine whether it is available after the computer is restarted." Default is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PowerShell Remoting is enabled on `$PC` something like this might work:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $PC { shutdown /r /f /d p:1:1 /t 300 /c $ARGV[0] } `
    -ArgumentList $reboot_reason
```

The `-Computer` option takes an array of names/IPs.

If you want to stick with your approach and just catch errors from `shutdown.exe`, evaluate `$LastExitCode` after the command:

```
shutdown /r /f /m \\$PC /d p:1:1 /t 300 /c "$reboot_reason" 2>$null
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) {
  Write-Host "Cannot reboot $PC ($LastExitCode)" -ForegroundColor black `
      -BackgroundColor red
} else {
  LogWrite "$env:username,$PC,Reboot Sent,$datetime"
}
```

`2>$null` suppresses the actual error message, and the check on `$LastExitCode` triggers the success/failure action.